# Why the first numbers generated by LCG don't repeat themselves?

Tags: r, simulation, random-generation

I wrote this algorithm to generate pseudo-random numbers from a Uniform distribution using a linear congruential generator. Looking at the results, I noticed that the first five numbers generated don't repeat, while most of the values from six onwards show a period length of 512.

```
gen_congr = function(n, M, a, c, seed) {
  x = seed
  out = rep(NA, n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    x = (a * x + c) %% M
    out[i] = x
  }
  out / M
}

y = gen_congr(1000000, 2^48, 5^17, 1, 1)

# y[1], y[2], ..., y[6], ...
which(y %in% y[1])
table(y)
```

I used the last two rows to quickly check repetitions.
I don't understand why this occurs and if the period length is actually 512 or more. Do I have to search repetitions in greater samples?

Comment: Could you explain what a "pseudo-casual number" might be??

Comment: I red that numbers generated with a congruential generator are pseudo-casual because the sequence isn't truly random. It's determined by the first value as in my algorithm (variable seed). I think every computational system isn't truly random.

Comment: Perhaps by "casual" you mean "random."

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In my language they are synonyms. Thank you for the note.

Comment: OK.  Turning to your question: could you please explain what you mean by "this occurs"?  Although you mention you perform some kind of check, what do you believe you are checking?  Are you aware that you are greatly overflowing the precision with which `R` performs calculations? Insert the line `cat(floor(log10(a*x+c)), "\n")` in the loop (and set `n` to a tiny number, such as 6) and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't understand. I tried what you suggested and the software generates six equal values. My algorithm is something like a school example, I think. I don't understand why most values show periodicity and others do not...

Comment: The computer is calculating with no more than 52 bits of precision but you are doing calculations requiring *at least* 88 bits. Thus, most of your calculations are not being performed correctly.